# How to enable up-arrow command history in Konsole

Tags: linux, terminal, konsole

Konsole, unlike Gnome terminal, does not seem to support up-arrow command history out of the box. Any way to enable it?

Comment: I thought such history is a shell thing. I'm not familiar with Gnome and its tools, but I think in general it's hard to implement history in terminal emulator without breaking other things (like interactive editors and such). But it may be that the terminal emulator sends unsupported sequence after up-arrow. Do you run the same shell (what shell?) in both cases? If so, screenshots of what happens will be useful. I use `konsole` with `bash` and up-arrow does work (the sequence is `^[[A` which is equivalent to [Ctrl+[](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation), [, Shift+a).

Comment: I use Konsole and there is an up-arrow history... but AFAIK this is a bash thing not a Konsole one.